# I haven't defined a stylesheet, but my webpage is styled

Tags: css

I am following a course via YouTube, and i followed along, but when I went to test my website, I saw a very weird favicon, which I didn't even define. The page also had its styling (h1 was smaller than h2) but i have never put a `<link>` tag in my page. The document is called index.html, so I tried to duplicate the file and call it something else, and the styling was gone. Does anyone know why?

UPDATE: I opened the page in Internet Explorer (I use Chrome) and it didn't show the style

Comment: Can you post the index.html file? If not then it is just blindly guessing.

Comment: sometimes chrome can do weird things with favicons. My todolist (a .txt file, so no formatting at all) currently bears facebook's favicon, and I don't know why. And I've long had an issue with firefox using cinnamon's style sheets randomly.

Comment: Can you post the code you have or a link to the Web page in question?

Answer (score 0):

There are six levels of headers from H1 to H6

In large font and in bold face, often separated with blank lines from the text. More important headings are generally rendered in a larger font than less important ones. H1 headings are often very large font, whereas H6 can be tiny

*`<Hn>heading text</Hn>`*

> example:

```html
<h1>H1</h1>
<h2>H2</h2>
<h3>H3</h3>
<h4>H4</h4>
<h5>H5</h5>
<h6>H6</h6>
```

**Firefox and Chrome implement this part of HTML but *IE*** (Internet Explorer) **doesn't**

Comment: That is not my issue. My h1 is smaller than h2, and I have a random favicon I did not define

Comment: oh sorry for that :) ,

if you are using local host:
check if you have any css file in the index.html folder
if no css files, check your desktop